# Can I remove mounting tabs from this gang box?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I need to install a 5-gang, old work box. This is the only one box available.

Should I just cut off the piece that gets screwed to the face of the 2x4 or notch out the drywall and fix?

I think the inside screws (both sides into studs) should be enough.

[image: 5-gang old-work box]

Comment: Unless specifically allowed in the instructions, removing the tabs would violate the UL listing for the box which requires that it be installed according to the instructions. Should there ever be a fire, this modified box _could_ be used to deny the claim.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use that. Use metal boxes. Specifically, you can get [*gangable* metal boxes](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Steel-City-1-Gang-3-in-12-5-cu-in-Old-Work-Metal-Electrical-Switch-and-Outlet-Box-Case-of-25-CDOW-25R/202596373):

[image: gangable box]

You can't tell from the picture, but they work. I have one in front of me right now - or rather, 2 of them connected. With one screw you can detach a side and then attach to another identical box. So for 2 gangs, you remove the left from one and the right from the other and then attach them *to each other*. For 3, 4, 5 you just repeat. Then you have all the benefits of a metal box - sturdy, fireproof, attach with screws where *you* want to, etc.

Comment: Just curious because I've used both.  Why the "Don't use that"?

Comment: @JACK For all the reasons that Harper, many others on DIY SE, and my own personal electrician (I know a lot, but I leave all the big stuff to a real electrician) always say to use metal boxes. I am not anti-plastic - for a lot of things it is great. But I have learned that for electrical boxes, metal is better.

Comment: +1 because I *am* anti-plastic as required by Chicago code, aside from the fact that the OP's isn't an old work box.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  That's a general rule of thumb... metal. You were pretty adamant about it so I thought you might have specifics.+1

Comment: Because, @JACK, "make your own" gangable boxes aren't made (to the best of my knowledge) in plastic, only in metal.

Comment: One additional note: Get the deepest boxes you can possibly find - go to an electrical supply place if necessary. There will be a _lot_ of wire supporting 5 switches and you'll want all the possible room to get all the wire bent into the box. Getting smaller boxes to save a dime will end up in frustration when it's time to install the devices and screw on the face plate.

Comment: I just saw this and I have a case of these boxes you can add a pair of battleships and now you have an old work box single gang or double gang no problem. They don’t strip out like plastic and as the answer states it’s a quick single screw, the top and bottom flanges can be removed on these if anchored usually through the back, but you can take the side off put the box in place hang it 2 screws and put the side back on. Very versatile boxes and they will out last plastic (plastic can not be used in many commercial or industrial jobs). + this OP really needs to go back and accept some answers